# Strange NSManagedObject behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm experiencing strange CoreData issue.
First of all, in my project i use lot of frameworks, so there are many sources of problem - so i considered to create minimal project which repeats my issue. You can clone [Test project on Github](https://github.com/soxjke/CoreDataTest) and repeat my test step-by-step.
So, the problem:
**NSManagedObject is tied to it's NSManagedObjectID which doesn't let object to be deleted from NSManagedObjectContext properly**
So, steps to reproduce:
In my AppDelegate, i setup CoreData stack as usual. AppDelegate has `managedObjectContext` property, which can be accessed to obtain NSManagedObjectContext for main thread. Application's object graph consists of one entity `Message` with `body`, `from`, `timestamp` attributes.
Application has only one viewController with only method viewDidLoad. It looks so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).managedObjectContext;

    NSEntityDescription *messageEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass([Message class]) inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // Here we create message object and fill it
    Message *message = [[Message alloc] initWithEntity:messageEntity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];

    message.body        = @"Hello world!";
    message.from        = @"Petro Korienev";

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    message.timestamp   = now;

    // Now imagine that we send message to some server. Server processes it, and sends back new timestamp which we should assign to message object.
    // Because working with managed objects asynchronously is not safe, we save context, than we get it's objectId and refetch object in completion block

    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error saving");
        return;
    }

    NSManagedObjectID *objectId = message.objectID;

    // Now simulate server delay

    double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
    {
        // Refetch object
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).managedObjectContext;
        Message *message = (Message*)[context objectWithID:objectId]; // here i suppose message to be nil because object is already deleted from context and context is already saved.

        message.timestamp = [NSDate date]; // However, message is not nil. It's valid object with data fault. App crashes here with "Could not fulfill a fault"

        NSError *error;
        [context save:&error];

        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error updating");
            return;
        }

    });

    // Accidentaly user deletes message before response from server is returned

    delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
    {
        // Fetch desired managed object
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).managedObjectContext;

        NSPredicate *predicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timestamp == %@", now];
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Message class])];
        request.predicate = predicate;

        NSError *error;
        NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error fetching");
            return;
        }

        Message *message = [results lastObject];

        [context deleteObject:message];
        [context save:&error];

        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error deleting");
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

Well, i detected app crash so i try to fetch `message` another way. I changed fetch code:

```
...
// Now simulate server delay

double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
{
    // Refetch object
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).managedObjectContext;

    NSPredicate *predicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timestamp == %@", now];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Message class])];
    request.predicate = predicate;

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching in update");
        return;
    }

    Message *message = [results lastObject];
    NSLog(@"message %@", message);

    message.timestamp = [NSDate date];

    [context save:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error updating");
        return;
    }

});
...
```

Which NSLog'ed `message (null)`
So, it shows:
1) Message is actually not existent in DB. It cannot be fetched.
2) First version of code someway kept deleted `message` object in context (Probably cause it's object id was retained for block call).
But why i could obtain deleted object by its id? I need to know.
Obviously, first of all, i changed `objectId` to `__weak`. Got crash even before blocks:)
[image]

So CoreData is built without ARC? Hmm interesting.
Well, i considered to `copy` NSManagedObjectID. What i've gotten?
[image]

```
(lldb) po objectId
0xc28ed20 <x-coredata://8921D8F8-436C-4CBC-B4AB-118198988D88/Message/p4>
(lldb) po message.objectID
0xc28ed20 <x-coredata://8921D8F8-436C-4CBC-B4AB-118198988D88/Message/p4>
```

See what's wrong? `NSCopying`'s `-copy` is implemented like `return self` on `NSManagedObjectID`
Last try was `__unsafe_unretained` for objectId. Here we go:

```
...    
    __unsafe_unretained NSManagedObjectID *objectId = message.objectID;
    Class objectIdClass = [objectId class];
    // Now simulate server delay

    double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
    {

        if (![NSObject safeObject:objectId isMemberOfClass:objectIdClass])
        {
            NSLog(@"Object for update already deleted");
            return;
        }
...
```

safeObject:isMemberOfClass: implementation:

```
#ifndef __has_feature
#define __has_feature(x) 0
#endif

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
#error ARC must be disabled for this file! use -fno-objc-arc flag for compile this source
#endif

#import "NSObject+SafePointer.h"

@implementation NSObject (SafePointer)

+ (BOOL)safeObject:(id)object isMemberOfClass:(__unsafe_unretained Class)aClass
{
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage"
    return ((NSUInteger*)object->isa == (NSUInteger*)aClass);
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
}

@end
```

Brief explanation - we use `__unsafe_unretained` variable, so at time of block call it can be freed, so we have to check whether it's valid object. So we save it's `class` before block (it's not retain, it's assign) and check it in block via `safePointer:isMemberOfClass:`
So for now, refetching object by it's managedObjectId is **UNTRUSTED** pattern for me.
Does anybody have any suggestions how i should do in this situation? To use __unsafe_unretained and check? However, this managedObjectId can be also retained by another code, so it will cause `could not fulfill` crash on property access. Or to fetch object everytime by predicate? (and what to do if object is uniquely defined by 3-4 attributes? Retain them all for completion block?). What is the best pattern for working with managed objects asynchronously?
Sorry for long research, thanks in advance.
P.S. You still can repeat my steps or make your own experiments with [Test project](https://github.com/soxjke/CoreDataTest)

Comment: I updated repo to contain correct implementation according to @Tommy's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `objectWithID:`. Use `existingObjectWithID:error:`. Per the documentation, [the former](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/objectWithID%3a):

> ... always returns an object. The data in the persistent store
>   represented by objectID is assumed to exist—if it does not, the
>   returned object throws an exception when you access any property (that
>   is, when the fault is fired). The benefit of this behavior is that it
>   allows you to create and use faults, then create the underlying data
>   later or in a separate context.

Which is exactly what you're seeing. You get an object back because Core Data thinks you must want one with that ID even though it doesn't have one. When you try to store to it, without having created an actual object in the interim, it doesn't know what to do and you get the exception.

`existingObject...` will return an object only if one exists.

Comment: Works like a charm! I was almost sure there should be simple solution in CoreData and i just didn't know it =) Thanks, next build of my app will be with `existingObjectWithID:error:` =)