# Concrete/complete example of using NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I'm still coding my RSS reader and I have gotten to the point where I'd like things to go smoother by background filling my Feeds at once with the newest Posts.

The problem is that it crashes my app quite badly with messages such as:

```
2013-10-02 21:06:25.474 uRSS[97209:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource 
must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

(stacktrace)

I came to the conclusion that I am not running thread safe here and I then discovered [this kind of CoreData snippets](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0j1XjjXV):

```
//Core Data's NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType and sharing objects between threads
[context performBlock:^{
    // fetch request code

    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        Class *firstObject = [results objectAtIndex:0];
        // do something with firstObject
    });
}];

// Assume we have these two context (They need to be set up. Assume they are.)
NSManagedObjectContext *mainMOC = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType] autorelease];
NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundMOC = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType] autorelease];

// Now this can safely be called from ANY thread:
[backgroundMOC performBlock:^{
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
    for (NSManagedObject *mo in results) {
        NSManagedObjectID *moid = [mo objectID];
        [mainMOC performBlock:^{
                NSManagedObject *mainMO = [mainMOC objectWithID:moid];
            // Do stuff with 'mainMO'. Be careful NOT to use 'mo'.
        }];
    }
}];
```

Now, what I would like to know is the following:

- should the backgroundMOC be defined as a Class member property, or everytime the method that uses it is invoked?
- what if this method is itself invoked asynchronously (the RSS parsing method create the objects on the fly)?
- How may I securely notify my UITAbleView that my MOC's been updated so that it can refresh without crashing?
- Does this only apply to fetches, or also to objects insertions, deletions, etc?
- Where could I find a working example of this concept successfully applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) backgroundMOC should be defined in the scope, where you use it. Say, if you use context inside of `SomeClass`, it's good to define it as property of `SomeClass`. However, usually many classes share same context (for example, it's quite OK to share `mainMOC` between all your viewControllers) so i suggest to define `mainMOC` and `backgroundMOC` in your AppDelegate or some other singleton.
2) It's OK. However, it's bad idea to create contexts every time — see 1 and initialize them once in singleton.
3) Take a look at [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It's exactly what you need to setup your tableView and track CoreData changes.
4) Yes
5) Cannot really point you to working example. Find something out on developer.apple.com =)

Also remarks:
1) Your class cannot be named Class
2) Use `existingObjectWithID:error:`, not `objectWithID:` — check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061132/strange-nsmanagedobject-behaviour) answer, it was really annoying issue in my experience
3) Read about [NSManagedObjectContext concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-SW39) patterns

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So, if I create my backgroundMOC in the method that async_dispatch the multiple object creation, then pass it as a parameter to this funciton, this would be ok, or worse? ATM, this just crashes when I tried to unfold a table section...

Comment: I think it's bad. If you'll have `backgroundMOC` and `mainMOC` as properties of appDelegate you'll never think whether you may or may not pass them somewhere. And it would be better not `dispatch_async` for `backgroundMOC` but `backgroundMOC performBlock:` as stays in your code snippet. `backgroundMOC performBlock:` - and do all stuff there, inside the block. If something was inserted/deleted/updatad - save context. However, for fetch and display something you have to use mainMOC.

Comment: Re-Thanks! How do I sync the mainMOC with the updated backgroundMOC? My problem is really that I async fetch multiple RSS feeds and want to insert the newly found posts in a background thread whilst notifying my GUI each time a new object is created so I can see the counters increasing...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdConcurrency.html - Track Changes in Other Threads Using Notifications section. Typically you have to use first pattern from it. Say - in your appDelegate, where you create contexts, you subscribe to `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`. In notification handler you simply `[mainMOC mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification]` and that's all! If you have NSFetchedResultsController setup - it will track changes already, because `mainMOC` will change during merge. Got it?

Comment: However, if you need some another kind of interaction - without NSFetchedResultsController - you can send your user-defined notifications from within `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` handler to your viewControllers.

Comment: I think you answered my questions, I have yet to do my homework and apply your wonderful explanations. Thanks.